# Recommend text on non-singular plane curves and DVRs

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, plane-curves, singularity, valuation-theory

> What are some recommend texts on the relationship between non-singular plane curves and DVRs?

I  am trying to study Hillman's paper [Singularities of plane algebraic curves](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82568768.pdf) and for this purpose I need some text on non-singularity of plane curves.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is DVR ? Think that acronyms should always be explicited.

Comment: Have you engaged with any of the standard texts for a first course in algebraic geometry? If so, which ones, and how well did they meet your needs?

Comment: @JeanMarie It's a **d**iscrete **v**aluation **r**ing, which should be very familiar to most answerers in the algebraic-geometry and commutative-algebra tags.

Comment: @KReiser Very familiar to some people maybe, but generally speaking there is a neat abuse of acronyms everywhere (not only on this site).

Comment: @KReiser yes I have studied Fulton's Algebraic Curves .It helped me in  basic concepts  but I want to study it in detail .I want to know If there is any specific text on  non-singularity of Plane curves?

Comment: There's not much to say, really: a plane curve over a perfect field is nonsingular iff the partial derivatives of it's defining equation don't all simultaneously vanish somewhere along the curve. This ought to be covered in any introductory text - for instance Hartshorne section I.5, or Vakil section 12.2. The local ring of a closed point on a curve is a DVR iff that's a regular point, which is a statement that ought to be located nearby (or you can prove it via algebra - any 1-dimensional regular local ring is a DVR).